# Java - How to add line breaks in swings

Tags: java, swing, line-breaks

I am adding a button to my minigame, but I do not know how to make a *line break*. I want one space in between the button and the text, and here's the code:

```
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Welcome to the Wall Game!");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Click the button to read the instructions!");
JLabel space = new JLabel("");
JButton button1 = new JButton("Start");
button1.setText("Start!");

label1.setFont(font1); 
panel1.add(label1); //adds in all the labels to panels
panel1.add(label2);
panel1.add(space);
panel1.add(button1);
this.add(panel1); //adds the panel
```

What it shows in the **Welcome message** in a separate line, but for some reason the button is beside `label2` Does someone know how?

By the way, you need `import javax.swing.*;` at the start if you didn't already know.
Thanks to anyone who knows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` by default, which obviously isn't meeting your needs.  You could use a `GridBagLayout` instead.

Have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Something like...

[image: Welcome]

```
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Welcome to the Wall Game!");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Click the button to read the instructions!");
JButton button1 = new JButton("Start");
button1.setText("Start!");

Font font1 = label1.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 24f);
label1.setFont(font1);

panel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
panel1.add(label1, gbc); //adds in all the labels to panels
panel1.add(label2, gbc);
gbc.insets = new Insets(30, 0, 0, 0);
panel1.add(button1, gbc);
```

as an example

Comment: [The Visual Guide to LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) is particularly useful in helping to find the appropriate LayoutManager for a desired look.